# Raspbian running headless doing scripted procedures on a internet page using text browser

Tags: xterm, xdotool, autologin, xvfb, w3m

I am somewhere between a new and intermediate linux user.

I am setting up a local network for a small group, and I need to configure an automatic sign-in to a webportal when internet connectivity is lost.

I have this working when I run my bash script with a monitor on the raspberry (RASPBIAN OS) itself, the sequence of things are:

Check if internet is down with fping --> Open xterm --> have xdotool open w3m and automate the clicks and inputting password.

Here is my code in condensed form:

```
    DNSPing=$(fping 9.9.9.9)
EtecsaPing=$(fping 10.180.0.30)
...
if [[  ( $EtecsaPing == "10.180.0.30 is alive" ) && ( $DNSPing == "9.9.9.9 is unreachable" ) ]]
then
echo "ETECSA UP - Internet all down - Run login script now"

xterm &
sleep 2
xdotool type "w3m -m https://10.180.0.30:8443/"
xdotool key Return
...
xdotool type <USER>
xdotool key Return
xdotool sleep 1
...
xdotool key Return
xdotool type <PASSWORD>
xdotool sleep 1
...
xdotool key Return

sleep 5

killall xterm

fi
```

So when I connect a monitor and mouse and run this it works just fine.

I want to have this running headless and with the script in crontab, and after 2 days of trying I feel like I'm just going in circles.

The problem is that both the new xterm session and xdotool requires a DISPLAY defined to run.

To that end I have installed xvfb which creates a simulated display.

```
sudo Xvfb :10 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24
DISPLAY=:10 xterm & (the script from above)
```

That runs without any errors, but it also does not work.

If I run:

```
 sudo Xvfb :10 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24
 DISPLAY=:10 xterm -e "echo 'deb blah ... blah' | sudo tee -a /CronJobs/yap.txt > /dev/null"
```

It adds the echo to the file, so I know that my display is running the xterm session, and I conclude the simulated display and xterm session is all working.

If I do:

```
sudo Xvfb :10 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24
DISPLAY=:10 xterm &
DISPLAY=:10 xdotool type "sudo echo 'deb blah ... blah' | sudo tee -a /CronJobs/yap.txt > /dev/null"
DISPLAY=:10 xdotool key Return
```

It does not work.

In conclusion, xdotool is working (no errors), but not doing anything!

So I'm thinking xdotool is not typing into the xterm terminal because the window is not selected, and I try to select the xterm window and I get:

```
DISPLAY=:10 xdotool getactivewindow
Your windowmanager claims not to support _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW, so the attempt to query the active window aborted.
xdo_get_active_window reported an error
```

And at this point my project is so unique that I can't find any good suggestions on what to do. A few people have tried to exchange the windowmanager for Xvfd but it's few and complicated.

Put in simple words:

- How can I make Xvfd act better like a real display?
- Can I make the linux forget all about DISPLAY variables and windowmanager, and just unconditionally run the script as a normal user? How?
- Can I automate my login sequence in a smarter way that would avoid xdotool?

My network is private and I have no issue with solutions that can compromise the security on the raspberry, so disabling whatever xhost etc is fine, I just don't see how/what.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

*I am answering my own question as Fosforo inspired me to try a few things that solved the issue.*

---

With your current suit of active programs, you cannot manipulate windows in `xvfb` using `xdotool`.

`xdotool` is still allowed to get information, for example, you can find the PID of your xterm window running the command:

```
DISPLAY=:10 xdotool search --name "xterm"
```

In your case, you got the PID of 2097165 for the active xterm session.

Now, you would normally activate the window with the command:

```
DISPLAY=:10 xdotool windowactivate 2097165
```

But when you run in `xvfb` this will return the following error:

```
Your windowmanager claims not to support _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW, so the attempt to activate the window was aborted.
xdo_activate_window on window:2097165 reported an error
```

So you can't actively manipulate the focus - You can find what the default focus of your `DISPLAY` is by running this command:

```
DISPLAY=:10 xdpyinfo | grep focus
```

This will inform you:

```
focus:  PointerRoot
```

Focus as `PointerRoot` means that anything you type is input into the window which is on your cursor.

Using the PID from before you quickly find the position and size of your xterm window by running the command:

```
DISPLAY=:10 xwininfo -id 2097165
```

This told you:

```
  Absolute upper-left X:  0
  Absolute upper-left Y:  0
  Relative upper-left X:  0
  Relative upper-left Y:  0
  Width: 484
  Height: 316
...
```

Using `xdotool` you can similarly get your mouse location:

```
DISPLAY=:10 xdotool getmouselocation
```

This tells you that your mouse location is:

```
x:512 y:384 screen:0 window:904
```

In other words; Your mouse is not on-top of the xterm window, so anything you type using xdotool type  is not put into the xterm window.

Two very easy solutions exist;

- Move the mouse
- Make the xterm window larger.

Since you know and control the screen resolution when starting `xvfb`, the second option is the easiest.

You merely add `-geometry` to the startup argument of xterm, so it becomes:

```
sudo Xvfb :10 -ac -screen 0 1024x768x24
DISPLAY=:10 xterm -geometry 1024x768+0+0 &
```

This will make the xterm window full size and thus ensure the mouse is above the window after which the `xdotool` commands such as key and type will work.

Adding the `-geometry` argument to xterm is in other words to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getwindowname` to debug it.

```
xdotool search --onlyvisible --name 'TITLE_YOUR_WINDOW' getwindowname
```

and output it to a file.

Some basic window managers accept `getwindowname` but not `getactivewindow`.

The second option is to use a vncserver. It works perfectly fine for headless desktops doing automated stuff. being doing for years.

Comment: Hey,the command suggested showed me that the xdotool is working - it did not solve the problem, but it gave me the insight to solve the problem, so thank you very much!!!